# Decoding base64 images in XML file with PHP

Tags: php, xml, base64

I'm trying to get product images from a proprietary ERP system into OpenCart.

So far (with the help of another answer on Stack Overflow) I have been able to save the images in separate files with this code:
http://pastebin.com/gv6M8QPT

A sample XML file looks like this:
http://pastebin.com/k6Eq4Rpr

There are 3 tags:

- id: in this case "1000"
- filename: in this case "sampleimage.jpg"
- mediablob: which is bin.base64 encoded image

Instead of simply saving the XML files I would now like to do the following:

1. Convert the mediablob in the XML file to the binary image file
2. Save the image file as `<id>.jpg` - where `jpg` is created based on the extention used in `<filename>` tag.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show us some code? What have you already tried?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. @Sjoerd have helped me getting the file encoded, and I just have to figure out how to make the filename right.
http://pastebin.com/DymXqF5Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the full solution.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$dataNodes = $document->getElementsByTagName('mediablob');
foreach ($dataNodes as $node) {
    // extract image
    $base64 = $node->textContent;
    // decode image
    $bin = base64_decode($base64);
    // get filename
    $filenames=$node->parentNode->getElementsByTagName('filename');
    $filename=$filenames->item(0)->textContent;
    // get ID
    $ids=$node->parentNode->getElementsByTagName('id');
    $id=$ids->item(0)->textContent;
    // get extension
    $extension=preg_replace("/^.+(?=\\.[^\\.]+$)/","",$filename);
    // save file
    file_put_contents($id.$extension, $bin);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfect! Really nice. Thanks also to all others who helped.

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
<?php
$im = file_get_contents('filename.gif');
$imdata = base64_encode($im);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$dataNodes = $document->getElementsByTagName('mediablob');
foreach ($dataNodes as $node) {
    $base64 = $node->textContent;
    $bin = base64_decode($base64);
    file_put_contents('image.jpg', $bin);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sjoerd. I now got it working and it saves an "image.jpg" file from my XML. 


This my program so far:
http://pastebin.com/DymXqF5Z


To solve the problem completely the image name should not be "image.jpg", but a file name created by the value of the tag <id> + the file extension used in tax <filename>. Because it may not always be jpg files. 

How can I make it save the files like thois?

Thanks for all help so far!